# query.where statement using date range in JS API

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, syntax

I'm trying to construct a query.where statement using 2 input type=date fields on the page.

The date field in SQL Server in the format 2014-12-31 00:00:00.0000000. The input fields date is in the format 2014-12-31. I am getting errors using the following statement.

```
function execute () {
    query.geometry = addressPoint;
    startDateQuery = document.getElementById("startDate").value
    endDateQuery = document.getElementById("endDate").value
    query.where = "(DATE_VAL >= " + startDateQuery + ") AND (DATE_VAL <= " + endDateQuery + ")";
    queryTask.execute(query, showResults);
}
```

If I use the REST interface however, 
`DATE_VAL >= '01-01-2014' AND DATE_VAL < '12-02-2014'`
works fine. So I am not sure if I need to use a formatting option for the query.where statemnent.

Date input fields:

```
        <div id="dateArea">
            Start Date: <input type="date" id="startDate" style="color:#333" /><br>
            End Date: &nbsp;<input type="date" id="endDate" style="color:#333" /><button id="SearchLightning" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button">Search</button>
        </div>
```

Comment: can you please confirm the exact values of `startDateQuery` and `endDataQuery`? What error message do you receive from the `queryTask.execute`?

Comment: From Dev toolserror: {code: 400, message: "Failed to execute query.", details: []}
code: 400
details: []
message: "Failed to execute query."

Comment: The exact values will be from the date input fields. I have added the code. When I used console.log(startDateQuery) is 2014-01-01 and console.log(endDataQuery) is 2014-12-31.

Comment: It looks like you need to transpose the date format from 2014-01-01 to 01-01-2014 (I'm not sure the best way to do this). You should also enclose the dates within single quotes: `query.where = "(DATE_VAL >= '" + startDateQuery + "') AND (DATE_VAL <= '" + endDateQuery + "')";`

Comment: @StephenLead Actually your code worked. I did not have to modify the date format at all. Thank you!

Comment: queryTask.execute throws up the error “Error: Failed to execute query.” on Internet Explorer 11 and EDGE but works fine on Chrome and Firefox browsers. The where condition works fine if I do not give date condition at all in the query for IE11, firefox, chrome, etc. -----------Case 1:-------------------------------- Case 1: Works fine on IE and other browsers when my where condition is hard coded query1.where="outlier = 0 and timestamp >= '1/24/2016 5:00:00 AM' and timestamp < '1/25/2016 5:00:00 AM'"; queryTask1.execute(query1, function(results1){.............}, function(error){........}); ---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that your REST query encloses the dates within single quotes:

`DATE_VAL >= '01-01-2014'`

To match this exactly, you need to enclose the dates within single quotes:

```
query.where = "(DATE_VAL >= '" + startDateQuery + "') AND (DATE_VAL <= '" + endDateQuery + "')";
```